# regular expression stop matching at

Tags: regex

I need to create an regular expression that stops at a `</script>` tag. For now I got this regular expression `((?!</(.*)script(.*)>).)*`. But this one fails completely as soon as a `</script>` tag is inside the string. I need to stop matching on this.

Is there any syntax feature I'm missing?

EDIT:

Expected input is this:

```
<script>
    function foo() {
    }
</script>
```

Expected output of the regular expression is:

```
    function foo() {
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do not use regex for parsing XML/HTML or anything of that nature. It's not worth it. Go for the real parser.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'm implementing it with a real parser. I just wanted to implement it in a two phase parser, e.g. parse HTML and JavaScript in a later step. I don't want to parse grammar with lexical grammar utility.

Comment: Do you want to capture everything before that script tag? Why not use something like `(.*)<\/script>`? In other words: What do you mean by "stops matching at"

Comment: @bash0r an example with expected output would be better.

Comment: @Cornelius Is there any way to remove the `</script>` tag from the matched value?

Comment: Take the content of the first capture group (everything matched by .*). The `</script>` won't be in there

Answer (score 0):

Answer for the edited question, try this regular expression:

```
(?:<script>)(.*)(?:<\/script>)
```

Important: Use the single line modifier (s). Example:
https://regex101.com/r/sC5lN2/2

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can help you https://regex101.com/r/pG2nP1/1

```
(?<=<script>)([^<>]+)(?=<\/script>)
```